# Ascribe array date to variable Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My array looks like:

```
$scope.names = [
    { "name": "John", "age" : "12" },
    { "name": "Ben", "age" : "15" },
    { "name": "Jason", "age" : "18" },
    { "name": "Billy", "age" : "11" }
];
```

I can show names.name in ng-repeat with this ;

```
<div ng-repeat="n in names"> {{n.name}} </div>
```

But can I ascribe names.name to the variable? Something like this:

```
var variable = names.name;
```

and then in ng-repeat write {{variable}}? I try to do that but it didn't works, Are there any methods to do that?

Comment: assign names.name to variable ex. var variable = names.name

Comment: not directly use names.name bcz it is array, you can use like: var variable = names[0].name;

Comment: This is clearly an [xy question problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/246392) why will you need such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

`names` is an array. So, you cannot use the notation `names.name`

You can assign it to a variable like:

```
var variable = names[0].name
```

But in this case, you can only access one element of the `names` array.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular.forEach() same as ng-repeat.

```
angular.forEach(obj, iterator, [context]);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach